# Wifi modulation and standard interoperability

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication

I've been reading [this summary](http://info.tek.com/www-wi-fi-overview-of-the-physical-layer-and-transmitter-measurements-primer.html)(info.tek.com) of Wifi standards from Tektronix, which seems to do a pretty decent job of explaining things, but has left me with a couple of questions:

- For access points that support multiple standards, how are the beacons transmitted? I would guess they use BPSK, but it's not clear whether this would be DSSS or OFDM (e.g. 802.11n devices don't support DSSS as far as I can see)
- When both the access point and end device support multiple standards (b/g/n seems pretty common) how do they decide which standard to use? I guess they let other devices know what they support through broadcasts/probe requests, so do they just default to the one offering highest data rates?

Comment: This question may be better suited for the electronics SE?